# Single pole AC to DC conversion circuit

Tags: transformer, mains

I am thinking about making a remote control light switch that fits into the existing light switch panel. And to power up the electronics that would requires a 3.3V DC supply.

The problem is, the panel has only two wires inside - 1. Live and 2. wires that goes to the light bulb. The neutral lines is not routed through the panel box.

Hence - a typical AC rectification + zener diode or transformer circuit that I found on this website couldn't be used. There is simply no neutral.

[This schematic](http://technosyndicate.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/powering-a-low-voltage-dc-load-from-a-single-pole-high-voltage-power-supply/) is the closet thing I have come across with my google-fu.

[image]

The capacitor got charged by the positive and negative cycle, I suppose.
But I want a continuous supply of DC for the microcontroller/radio, I am not sure how to modify that.

Thanks.

Comment: I would never follow a high voltage design that contains the comment "Are diodes placed the right way?"

Comment: Me neither. That comment surprised me too. I think that's doable because there are commercial product for this (with just live and bulb wire connection), and the idea of charging the cap + zener like that sounds doable. I don't know if commercial product are using this charging method though. Maybe I should just tear one down? Though those product I could source around are controlled by dedicated RF, not Bluetooth/Zigbee/X10 - that's why I want to re-invent the wheel, sort of.

Comment: Your circuit has only one wire going to it.  I hope that isn't what you meant by "single pole"!

Answer (score 1):

First, realize that the circuit you found is not isolated, and **every** piece of metal in it should be considered "hot", with potentially lethal voltages present.

Second, current doesn't flow in a circuit, and parts do not function, unless there is actually a "complete circuit" present. That means that current must flow in to the circuit from a power source and have a path to *return* to the power source. This circuit, as drawn, does not have this, and so it can not function.

If it does work in real life, it may be because there is a parasitic capacitive path back to the building ground. But it doesn't appear the designer has any idea what this path is or what its behavior is. It is probably unreliable, and could change if the circuit is moved around, put in a different enclosure, etc. I would not recommend to use this circuit.

The best solution I can offer is to rewire your switch: go into the attic or basement, break into the existing junction box or add a new one, and pull a new wire, with a neutral, to your switch. Be sure to observe your local code on issues such as the maximum number of junctions in a box of a given size. Depending on jurisdiction you may need to hire a licensed professional to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with an incandescent bulb, then you can model it as a small value resistor (eg a 240V 100W lamp has an on resistance of ~570R, but an off resistance of a few ohms).

This means that if you put a large value resistor in your device, a voltage will appear across it while the bulb does not light. From that you can start to design a power supply. Note that when your device is "on" (presumably in a triac), you won't have a power supply. So you'll end up chopping a small bit off the front of each waveform for power, and storing it in a capacitor.

(NOTE: NOT TESTED, UNLIKELY TO PASS ANY SAFETY REGULATIONS, WILL NOT WORK WITH OTHER BULB TYPES)